# C# syntax for accesing properties by name in string

Tags: c#, .net

I ran into this C# code which apparently allows me to access the object's properties in a single method by their name in an input string. I assume its a relatively new C# feature. Can someone tell me what it's called and the reference to the documentation?

```
    public class ExamValidation : Exam, IDataErrorInfo
    {

//...
        public string this[string columnName]
        {
//---
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called an [*indexer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) and it is not new - it has been in C# from the beginning.  It's simply another way of looking up data in a collection (by string rather by an integer index).

It's found in data structures where the *order* of elements in not as important as looking up data by a string key, such as a dictionary or data table (looking up row data by column name instead of order).

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx for more.

Answer (score 2):

This is called an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) and it's not new at all. These have been around since the first iteration of the framework. Indexers are *commonly* seen with `int` values, like an array for example, but they can receive any type. Note the documentation:

> Indexers do not have to be indexed by an integer value; it is up to you how to define the specific look-up mechanism.

So, in this case it's looking up data with a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

This is telling me that the class has an indexer so you can save an array/list of values.